# Excel pivot like Data transformaton using R

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have data in 2 columns

```
VisitNumber,Scored Labels
1,30
1,38
1,38
1,38
2,39
2,39
2,999
2,999
3,36
3,999
4,42
6,25
6,999
```

I want unique values of scored labels as column names and data as count of visitnumber.

[image: Sample look of data format]

Please help me how can I do this in R.

Comment: Which web site/twitter account/redditer is the one recommending this "post screen shots from RStudio data viewer" trend?

Comment: The data in the image and the data you have given us contradict. Please give us consistent data to work with.

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Some effort of your own wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: .  Try `library(reshape2);dcast(df1, VisitNumber~ScoreLabels, value.var='VisitNumber', function(x) sum(x!=0))`

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun You are the best!!